# Image display problems on Windows Phone 8

Tags: bug, status-norepro, mobile-web, cdn

When using my Windows Phone 8 there are a number of images that do not do display correctly.

These have never displayed correctly ever since I got it, I've cleared my browser cache as well as hard reseting my phone - not just to resolve this issue :).

**From the pop-up menu:**

> [image: Pop-Up Menu]

**From the user page:**

> [image]

EDIT: This appears to a problem getting the image from the CDN. For example, http://cdn.sstatic.net/outdoors/img/favicon.ico loads fine on a WP 7 device, but not on Windows Phone 8.

Comment: This looks to be fixed in today's update to the Mobile Notification bar.

Thanks all :D

Answer (score 1):

It seems to have been a CDN problem which went away.

I can't replicate: can you confirm it's fixed? I will assume there is no work needed unless notified otherwise.

Comment: Yes this is fixed. I added a comment  back in January that the new mobile design sorted it.